# are organizations that receive certificates considered "end entities" in a PKI?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I am trying to understand the term [end-entity](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Apache-WebDAV-LDAP-HOWTO/glossary.html). Does this term just mean anybody that plays a role in a PKI system that is not a CA? So if I request a certificate from A who is a CRL issuer for Verisign then am I an end entity to verisign? Is A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *end-entity certificate* is a certificate which is not used to validate signatures on other certificates, i.e. a certificate which does not contain a CA public key (its `Basic Constraints` extension is absent, or contains a `cA` flag with value `FALSE`). It is called "end-entity" because it appears, necessarily, at the end of a certificate path.

A CRL issuer certificate, i.e. a certificate for some entity who signs CRL (on behalf of a CA), can be an end-entity certificate, since signing CRL does not require to be a CA.