# Do all non-CA certs have to be End Entity certs?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Do all non-CA certs have to be End Entity certs?

Comment: "End Entity" is straight from X.509, so it is accepted widespread terminology -- except that X.509 is (as usual) rather fuzzy on the exact definition.

Answer (score 9):

"End Entity" is defined in [X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-3) (well,RFC 5280) as:

```
 end entity: user of PKI certificates and/or end user system that is
             the subject of a certificate;
```

but the expression really makes sense in the context of *path validation*: an "EE" certificate is called that way because when it appears in a certificate path, it is necessarily at the end of the path. In that sense, an "EE certificate" is a certificate that either does not contain a [Basic Constraints extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9), or that contains such an extension with the `cA` flag equal to `FALSE`.

Now you can validate a CA certificate by putting it at the end of a path, in which case that certificate, though it belongs to a Certification Authority, can temporarily be an "end-entity certificate", depending on how you interpret that expression. The relation goes in the other direction: as per the [path validation algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6) (specifically section [6.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6.1.4), step (k)), for a certificate to be able to appear in a valid path at any place other than the end, it MUST be a "CA certificate" (meaning here "a certificate with a Basic Constraints extension with the `cA` flag set to `TRUE`).

This answers your question: if a certificate is not a "CA certificate" (as in "certificate *tagged* as being 'CA'", as opposed to "certificate *owned* by an organization that is also a Certification Authority"), then it may be used only as "end entity" within a validation path.

(Or, said otherwise: don't try to read too much in some ill-defined terminology. In practice, what matters is what implementations *do*, i.e. the path validation algorithm.)

Answer (score 2):

> Do all non-CA certs have to be End Entity certs?

Yes. It's an either/or-thing according to [RFC 5280, section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-12):

```
X.509 v3 also includes an extension that identifies the subject of a
certificate as being either a CA or an end entity, reducing the
reliance on out-of-band information demanded in PEM.

This specification covers two classes of certificates: CA
certificates and end entity certificates.  CA certificates may be
further divided into three classes: cross-certificates, self-issued
certificates, and self-signed certificates.
```

Also: Similar question here: [Are organizations that receive certificates considered “end entities” in a PKI?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34800/are-organizations-that-receive-certificates-considered-end-entities-in-a-pki)

Comment: This does however depend on the definition of CA certificate. For X509 certs it is a boolean flag, in normal communication the "CA Certificates" refer to the root certificates (but not in all cases). So basically you have end-entity certificates and a certificate chain containing multiple types of CA certificates like intermediate (which can be organisation or CA owned) and root certificate (CA owned).

Answer (score 0):

X.509 certificates are documents that are designed to hold information that is certified to be an exact, unchanged copy of critical security information. The certifier is usually a mutually trusted third party. That information consists of several important values, but right now you need to understand just a few: the name of the organization to whom the certificate belongs, that organization's public key, a field indicating what actions that public key is allowed to be used for, the identity/identities of the signer/signers, and the signature itself.

Certification is done by someone at the signing authority evaluating the information honestly came from the organization named on the certificate, then attesting to it by hashing the bits of the certificate (using SHA, MD5, or other hash algorithm), then encrypting that hash-digest value with the super-secret private key of the signing authority. This produces the signature. Anyone with the public key of the signing authority can use it to validate the rest of the document hasn't been changed.

Signing authorities are trusted by OS and browser makers to provide "self-signed" certificates - certificates that are signed by the authority itself. These certificates have the name of the signing authority, their public key, and a field that says it can only be used to validate signatures. These are called Trusted Root certificates, and the organizations who issue them are called Certificate Authorities (CAs).

When an organization wants to let users encrypt their traffic, they create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR). The CSR has their name, their public key, and a flag that says this public key is to be used only to encrypt encryption keys. They send the CSR to their CA, who (for a fee) validates it came from a legitimate source, then signs their request, producing a certificate.

Sometimes a CA will not use their root key to directly sign every certificate. This is common in enterprise level installations. Instead, the root certificate signs a different certificate that has the flag set to "validate signatures". This secondary certificate is a 'working' certificate, and is used to create the thousands of other certificates used in the day-to-day operations (email user certificates, web server farm certificates, client certificates, etc.) These are called Certificate Subordinate Authorities (CSAs). It is not uncommon for a very big organization to have one CSA dedicated to signing email certificates, a different CSA signing internal web server certificates, and a different one signing client computer certificates.  This overall architecture is referred to as a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI).

Comment: How is this an answer to the question that was asked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all non-CA certs have to be End Entity certs.

### A simple way to see it

- If a certificate is entitled to sign other certificates, then it is the certificate of a Certificate Authority (CA)
- Certificates can sign certificates that are again entitled to sign other certificates - we call this a certificate chain
- If a certificate is not entitled to sign other certificate, then the certificate chain ends here - hence the name End Entity (EE)

### Additional info

If a certificate is entitled to sign other certificates, is determined by the these attributes:

```
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
```

(CRL Sign is optional, but obviously makes a lot of sense)

Answer (score -1):

Answer is No. 
We do have intermediate certificate authority which is neither ROOT CA  nor End Entity.

The purpose of using an intermediate CA is primarily for security. 
Generally Root CA is kept in a same location for security reasons.
Root CA signs the intermediate CA, intermediate CA signs the End Entity.

There can be more then one Intermediate CA.

ROOT CA
  |
  |
Intermediate CA
  |
  |
End Entity Certificate.

Comment: Prakash, the question asks about CA certs in general and doesn't specify root v. intermediary CAs so the answer is yes, not no. Everything else you said is correct, but getting the answer right seems sort of a big deal.